# PCI error messages on Lenovo B50-10

Tags: lenovo

Recently I've installed Ubuntu LTS 16.04 on a new Lenovo B50-10 laptop. Apparently everything is working properly, however some error messages apppears regarding pci devices on dmesg.

```
dmesg |grep fail

[    1.268776] pci 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[    1.268789] pci 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[    1.268803] pci 0000:00:1c.1: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[    1.268830] pci 0000:00:1c.1: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[    1.268839] pci 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 14: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
[    1.268852] pci 0000:00:1c.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
```

And some other messages like this:

```
[    0.537659] pci 0000:00:1c.1: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
```

I've searched this errors on google, and everything indicates it could be a bios bug.  Beside, a related error message appears on dmesg output, as you can see above:

```
[    2.867219] pci 0000:00:1d.0: EHCI: BIOS handoff failed (BIOS bug?) 01010001
```

- I've updated the bios with the new version available on Lenovo support site, v2.07 at this point, released on Oct-2016, but the problem remain.
- If I pass the option 'acpi=off' to the kernel, no error messages appears, but wifi card doesn't work.
- If a fix 'OS Optimized default' to Enabled on Bios, and hit 'Load default settings', the errors remain.

IMHO, everything is related with a bios bug. In the past, I've suffered a similar problem with a Lenovo b50-30, but in that case, a bios update fixed the problem.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thans in advance,

Best Regards.

Comment: If everything in Ubuntu works fine, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I've found a possible explanation to this error messages in this thread:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1426216

------- Comment From <email address hidden> 2015-06-16 21:21 EDT-------
The PHB3 PCIe host bridge in Power8 does not support generating IO space transactions / cycles, so no IO window is assigned to the PCI bus and all IO space resources will be unassigned and must remain disabled in the pci command register. (Previous bridges in most PowerPC systems provided a memory mapped window that generates IO cycles but that function was not implemented in Power8.)

Answer (score 2):

run the firmware test suite, fwts klog test on a freshly booted system, it may explain some of those error messages:

```
apt-get install fwts
fwts klog -
```

Comment: The firmware test suite is interesting in that it reads the kernel log file for errors and warnings and explains what they mean. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the answer!. I paste the result, not very useful info:

```
Results generated by fwts: Version V16.03.00 (2016-03-14 09:10:20).

Some of this work - Copyright (c) 1999 - 2016, Intel Corp. All rights reserved.
Some of this work - Copyright (c) 2010 - 2016, Canonical.

This test run on 18/12/16 at 01:03:27 on host Linux lenovo 4.4.0-53-generic
#74-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64.

Command: "fwts klog -".
Running tests: klog.

klog: Scan kernel log for errors and warnings.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test 1 of 1: Kernel log error check.
Kernel message: [ 0.030056] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'

ADVICE: This is not exactly a failure but a warning from the kernel. The
MSR_IA32_ENERGY_PERF_BIAS was initialized and defaulted to a high performance
bias setting. The kernel has detected this and changed it down to a 'normal'
bias setting.

Kernel message: [ 0.164916] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored

ADVICE: This is not exactly a failure mode but a warning from the kernel. The
_OSI() method has implemented a match to the 'Linux' query in the DSDT and this
is redundant because the ACPI driver matches onto the Windows _OSI strings by
default.

FAILED [CRITICAL] KlogAcpiNoValidCrt: Test 1, CRITICAL Kernel message: [
1.473105] [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found

ADVICE: No valid ACPI _CRT (Critical Trip Point) was found.

Found 1 unique errors in kernel log.

================================================================================
0 passed, 1 failed, 0 warning, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.
================================================================================


0 passed, 1 failed, 0 warning, 0 aborted, 0 skipped, 0 info only.

Test Failure Summary
================================================================================

Critical failures: 1
 klog: CRITICAL Kernel message: [    1.473105] [Firmware Bug]: No valid trip found

High failures: NONE

Medium failures: NONE

Low failures: NONE

Other failures: NONE

Test           |Pass |Fail |Abort|Warn |Skip |Info |
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
klog           |     |    1|     |     |     |     |
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
Total:         |    0|    1|    0|    0|    0|    0|
---------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: fwts is useful because it points to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1553691 and the solution is to get the latest BIOS update from Lenovo.